# Content-Type: text/html Issue During PDF Download in Web Applications

Tags: react, spring-boot, jasper-reports

I would like to ask for your help today. I am building an API, and it has an endpoint to download a receipt in PDF format. When I test this endpoint in Postman, it works fine, generating the PDF and allowing me to download it without any issues. However, in the frontend, when I try to download the PDF, it downloads but with a different file size than it should be, and it won't open, generating this message (Error: Failed to load PDF document). I will leave my code available for you to understand better

```
const handledownloadReceipt = async (punterId: number, userId: number) => {
   try {
     const url = `/receipts/export-pdf?punterId=${punterId}&userId=${userId}`;

     const response = await axios.get(url, {
       responseType: 'blob',
       withCredentials: true,
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
         Pragma: 'no-cache'
       }
     });

     console.log('Tamanho: ' + response.data.size);
     console.log('Tipo: ' + response.data.type);
     console.log('Id do apostador: ' + punterId);
     console.log('Id do Usuario: ' + userId);

     const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
     const link = document.createElement('a');
     link.href = blobUrl;
     link.setAttribute('download', 'recibo.pdf');
     document.body.appendChild(link);
     link.click();
     window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
     link.remove();
   } catch (error) {
     console.error('Erro ao baixar o recibo', error);
   }
 };
```

Size: 721, Type: text/html, Punter Id: 4, User Id: 1, I am relatively new to programming and am currently dedicating myself to extensive studies in this field. I express my sincere gratitude to everyone who offers their assistance and guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by doing it this way:

```
const handleDownloadReceipt = async (your parameters here if any) => {
    try {
      const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `API HERE`,
        responseType: 'blob',
        withCredentials: true
      };

      const response = await requestBackend(config);

      const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = downloadUrl;
      link.setAttribute('download', 'recibo.pdf');
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
      link.remove();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error downloading the receipt:', error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).